# drupal 6: how to email users of tasks due (week b4, day before, and overdue)

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

Using open atrium, have tasks with assigned to (user reference) field, due date field, neither field required. Also using flag to note if task is completed or not.

Want to email users a reminder of tasks when that task's due date is a week away, again when it's the day before, and each day when it is overdue.

If task has a due date, if due date is X-time away or past due, if task is not complete, if task is assigned to someone, then email reminder to their registered email address.

Tried doing a rule to run on cron, but don't see this type of options. Looked at scheduler, auto expire, node expire, they don't work the way I need.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) module. It does what you ask for. If you can't / wont use it, you can take a look at how it handles the sending of email reminders.